# Blank labels after data passing in Swift 4?

Tags: swift

I am currently trying to pass data from my table view controller to a second view controller but my labels and image are appearing as blank in the second view controller.

This is my main event view controller:

```
class EventsTableViewController: PFQueryTableViewController {


    override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery<PFObject> {
        let query = PFQuery(className: "Events")
        //query.order(byAscending: "location")
        query.order(byAscending: "date")
        return query
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.title = "Upcoming Events"
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

    func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

            if segue.identifier == "MasterToDetail" {
                let detailVC = segue.destination as!  DetailViewController
               detailVC.myEventCell = sender as? EventCell 
            }
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> PFTableViewCell? {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! EventCell

        cell.dateLabel.text = object?.object(forKey: "date") as? String
        cell.locationLabel.text = object?.object(forKey: "location") as? String
        cell.nameLabel.text = object?.object(forKey: "name") as? String

        let imageFile = object?.object(forKey: "image") as? PFFile

        cell.eventImage.image = UIImage(named: "download")

        cell.eventImage.file = imageFile
        cell.eventImage.loadInBackground()

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "MasterToDetail", sender: EventCell())

    }

    @IBAction func reloadTable(_ sender: Any) {

        self.loadObjects()
    }

            @IBAction func onSignOutTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        let firebaseAuth = Auth.auth()
        do {
            try firebaseAuth.signOut()
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "signOutSegue", sender: nil)
            } catch {
            print (error)
        }

    }

}
```

and my second view controller:

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var detailImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var detailNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var detailDescriptionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var detailLocationLabel: UILabel!

    var myEventCell: EventCell?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setUI()
    }
    func  setUI () {
        detailNameLabel.text = myEventCell?.nameLabel.text
        detailImageView.image = myEventCell?.eventImage.image
        detailLocationLabel.text = myEventCell?.locationLabel.text
    }

}
```

Comment: Please don't pass a cell (the view). Don't do that. Pass the object of the data source (the model).

Answer (score 0):

As you send an empty cell here

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "MasterToDetail", sender: EventCell())
```

You need

```
let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at:indexPath)
performSegue(withIdentifier: "MasterToDetail", sender:cell)
```

Comment: still not working, still getting blank space on the labels